# Handlebars, if else if custom helper

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm having an issue figuring out just how to structure my handlebars helper. I have this special case where i get a list of 5 different signs where i need to apply them to an element.

The list is as follows:

1. Custom Sign
2. Sold
3. Open house
4. New
5. New price

I've solved it with this block, but I pretty much cringe every time i look at it and want to move it into a helper to clean up the markup.

```
            <div class="case-image" data-img-src="{{image_url}}">
              {{#if sign_url }}
                <div class="case-sign">{{sign_url}}</div>
              {{else}}
                {{#if solgt}}
                <div class="case-sign">Solgt</div>
                {{else}}
                  {{#if aabenthus}}
                  <div class="case-sign">Åbent hus</div>
                  {{else}}
                    {{#if nyhed}}
                    <div class="case-sign">Nyhed</div>
                    {{else}}
                      {{#if ny_pris}}
                      <div class="case-sign">Ny pris</div>
                      {{/if}}
                    {{/if}}
                  {{/if}}
                {{/if}}
              {{/if}}
              <a href="{{page_url}}"></a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to use an "enumerated" type instead of using 5 separate flags for each type. If the type is `Custom Sign`, then the `customValue` is used. Otherwise, a predetermined string for the type is returned.

**Handlebars file**

```
<div class="case-image" data-img-src="{{image_url}}">
   <div class="case-sign">{{sign type customValue}}</div>
       <a href="{{page_url}}"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**In browser JS:**

```
// Enumeration for type of house
var Types = {
  'Custom Sign': 1,
  'Sold': 2,
  'Open house': 3,
  'New': 4,
  'New price': 5
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('sign', function(type, customValue) {
    var ret = '';

    if (type === Types['Custom Sign']) {
      ret = customValue || '';
    } else if (type === Types['Sold']) {
      ret = 'Solgt';
    } else if (type === Types['Open house']) {
      ret = 'Åbent hus'
    } else if (type === Types['New']) {
      ret = 'Nyhed';
    } else if (type === Types['New house']) {
      ret = 'Ny pris'; 
    }

    return ret;
});
```

**If you're using express, set up the view engine with helpers this way**

```
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

var hbs = exphbs.create({
  helpers: {
     sign: function(type, customValue) {
       // same implementation as above
     }
  },
  extname: '.hbs', // optional - edit as desired
  layoutsDir: './views/', // optional - edit as desired
  defaultLayout: 'layout' // optional - edit as desired
});

app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Comment: The problem is that i dont want to start injecting into the json object.

I get the json part something like this 

{
custom_sign: ''
solgt: ''
åbenthus: '1'
nyhed: '1'
ny_pris: ''
}